# Voltage conversion & input circuit for Raspberry Pi

Tags: gpio

I want to convert a 24V signal from sensors to 3.3V input signal for a Raspberry Pi. I have almost 20 sensors, so I have to convert all to 3.3V.

Is there any IC from which I can do multiple voltage conversions coming from many sensors? What is the additional ckt to used, to remove the floating value of input?

Comment: Is this an analog signal? or Digital?

Comment: digital signal . High and  Low

Comment: What do you mean by "ckt"? Do you mean "circuitry"?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple voltage divider circuit that should meet your requirements - note that the upper resistor will be sinking nearly half a watt when the input is 24V so should be 0.5W rating - 0.6W is a common rating for some manufacturers so should be easy to source...

This will draw over 2 milliamps with a 24V input voltage if that is important for the circuit under test.

[image: Simple voltage divider using a 10K resistor in upper arm and 1.5K in lower to divide 24 volts DC down to 3.1 volts to feed into a GPIO pin on an RPi]

Drawn using GSchem, part of the GPLed GNU [Geda](http://www.geda-project.org/) package.

Comment: I know the OP talks about external signal but I think its worth mentioning that sending data BACK to the sensor is not possible with this circuit. PS Did you know Pi Exchange has a schematic editor now?

Comment: The OP did mention "input signals" so I took that to mean sending data back is **NOT** wanted - so it is a valid answer - though your point is valid for anyone seeking a bi-directional level conversion - it is possible but it needs active (semiconductor) devices.  PS Yeah I know about the schematics editor but I keep my web-browser locked down with NoScript and RequestPolicy and I wasn't keen to jump through the additional hoops to get all the JavaScript working to use it - when I have a perfectly good schematic editor installed and in use - though it does mean posting "dumb" pictures...! 8-P

Comment: Hi, not critisizing that your answer was wrong or anything. I think its a great answer - Just wanted to alert you and other that it doesn't support sending signals back thats all.  OK, cool, it sounds like you locked down tightly on your side ;) I jsut block flash for now, not had any issues since flash ads stopped showing on my side. But thanks, even pictures are amazing to add to content.

Answer (score 1):

That's a hardware question, not a RPi question.

Use two resistors for each sensor to make a voltage divider.  A calculator like [this](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Voltage-Divider-Calculator.phtml) will help you get the right values, and it includes a picture of how to hook it up.  If the resistors get hot from the current, then you need bigger ones, or you need to use a different method.

[Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=42938) is a good discussion of Optocouplers

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain _how_ the optocouplers would help? Also, as links are liable to die over time, could you provide a synopsis of the link?